# Javascript object literal notation, using functions

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an object using literal notation. Is it possible to have some of the properties use previously defined properties as their value?

For example:

```
    var test = {
        prop1: obj1, 
        prop2: obj2,
        prop3: (prop1!=null)?prop1:prop2
    };
```

Comment: could you please be more specific?  From your example I don't really see what the nature of the question is, because you should be able to test it out fairly easily.  Is there a more detailed example you inted to be showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do something like `var x = { 'a': 1, 'b': x.a }` then it won't work. Since `x` is not finished being defined.

But you can do something like

```
var
    a = 12,
    b = 24,
    c = a + b; // 36
```

This is because each var definition is interpreted sequentially. Basically equivalent to

```
var a = 12;
var b = 24;
var c = a + b;
```

But with objects and arrays the entire definition is interpreted one time.

Answer (score 1):

No and yes.

The following aren't possible:

```
var o = {
    a : 42,
    b : o.a //raises a TypeError, o is not defined
};

var o = {
    a : b : 42 //raises a SyntaxError, unexpected :
};
```

The following, however, are:

```
//referencing a pre-existing variable is obviously possible
var ans = 42;
var o = {
    a : ans,
    b : ans
};

var o = {
    a : 42
};
//after the variable has been declared, you can access it as usual
o.b = o.a;
```

If you feel limited by the value being a single statement, you can always use an anonymous function:

```
var o = {
    a : (function () {
        doStuff();
        return otherStuff();
    }())
};
```

Answer (score 0):

to keep your example:

```
var test = {
  prop1: obj1,
  prop2: obj2,
  prop3: (function () {
    return (test.prop1!=null)?test.prop1:test.prop2;
  })()
};
```